# Redirect process stdin and stdout to SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, redirection

I have an embedded linux application with a simple interactive command line interface, running on Debian 9.

I'd like to access the command line via SSH over network.
something similar to this - [redirect application to netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311287/redirect-process-stdin-and-stdout-to-netcat), but over SSH for security reasons.

I know that SSH is usually used to share the entire shell, is it possible to expose only specific application?

In additon, the application has its own authentication procedure (in terms on user/password during bringup) , is it possible to skip/customize the authentication phase used by default with the SSH server?